# Dividing a number leaded by a 0

Tags: php

How are numbers(int, float) leaded with a 0 divided in PHP.

Below is what I tried:

```
echo 016/2; // 7
echo 08/2;  // Invalid numeric literal
echo 09/2;  // Invalid numeric literal
echo 010/2; // 4
echo 00000000000000000010/2; // 4
echo 07/2; // 3.5 Correct
```

I have tried the above calculations as a string, int and float.

Comment: A number "leaded by a 0" is treated as an octal value by PHP, as described in the [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integer literals are documented at *PHP Manual/ Language Reference/ Types/ [Integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)*:

> Integers can be specified in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base
>   16), octal (base 8) or binary (base 2) notation, optionally preceded
>   by a sign (- or +).
>
> Binary integer literals are available since PHP 5.4.0.
>
> To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero). To use
>   hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x. To use binary
>   notation precede the number with 0b.

`08` is an invalid octal number, just like `0xZZZ` is invalid hexadecimal.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why `08` was throwing an error